# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created two folders in my Documents directory. 
I have a UITableView which shows the items in the folders.

```
Subfolder = @"/Sent";
```

It gives me a Threat 1: signs SIGABRT on the line:

```
NSString *last = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I have two table views, this code below has been working fine until I added the 2 folders to the documents directory.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [_arrConnectedDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([filePathsArray count] == 0){
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subFolder]];
            filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath  error:nil];
        }
        if ([filePathsArray count] > 0) {

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subFolder]];
            filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath  error:nil];
            NSString *last = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSString *last2 = [[last lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
            cell.textLabel.text = last2;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

When I open one folder with a file in it, it loads fine, after, if i open the folder with nothing in it, I get the below error.
If i first open the folder with nothing in it, its fine, then open the folder with something in it, its fine, then when I go back to the empty folder, again the same error. 
What am I missing here?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: Add Exeption Breakpoint and just debug this.

Comment: Try to pass an `NSError` variable to the line you re-set `filePathsArray` and check if it reports any error.

Answer (score 1):

You reassign `filePathsArray` in the middle of your method. You then access objects at an index without checking if it's inside the bounds of the array. That's most likely not correct.

```
if ([filePathsArray count] > 0) {
    /* ... */
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath  error:nil];
    NSString *last = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The number of objects in filePathsArray can be less than indexPath.row after you have reassigned it.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but I am quite new to iOS development which is probably obvious. What would be the correct way of displaying the Subfolder in Documents in my table view?